# How does Visual Studio select the Azure Functions Tools version?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

In

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases
```

I have two versions of the Azure Functions Tools: 4.18.1 and 4.30.0

How does Visual Studio decide, which version it uses? If I check my .csproj file, I can only find that it specifies version 4, no exact version:

```
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Versioned Folders present in the local path `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases` are not the Azure Functions Core Tools Versions.

> I have two versions of the Azure Functions Tools: 4.18.1 and 4.30.0

I believe those are the Updates to the Azure Functions Core Tools Main Versions (1.x, 2.x, 3.x and 4.x) - [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4,windows,csharp,portal,bash#v2):
[image]

[image]

There will be a **json** file `feed` in the above Path of AzureFunctionsTools that explains the above versioned folders are the kind of patch updates of Pre-release and General availability:

[image]

All the Details of the Azure Functions Core Tools Patch Updates releases along with the compatible services information given in the `feed-v2167102.json` file.

> How does Visual Studio decide, which version it uses? If I check my .csproj file, I can only find that it specifies version 4, no exact version:

Earlier, I have the Azure Functions Core Tools Version `4.0.4785`
[image]

Now, I have installed the latest Version `4.0.4915` from the GitHub [Source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases) of AFCT and the current version is:

[image]

[image]

Whatever the latest version installed, that can be taken by the Visual Studio IDE and it will show only major version in the form of **v4**.

**For AFCT v3 - .NET 3.1 Project**:

```cs
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

**For AFCT v4 - .NET 6 Project**:

```cs
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

[image]